# Why is cin apparently skipping input in this C++ code?

Tags: c++, cin, cout

I have a simple C++ test code.  The way it should work is for a user to enter a sequence of integers through `cin`, followed by some character to terminate the `cin` input, then the code should output the integers.  Next, the user should enter an integer other than zero to input another sequence.  If that's what the user does, the process begins again, otherwise the code exits.

For example, I am expecting input

```
1 2 3 4 5 a
```

to result in output

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

followed by an opportunity to input the signal for another sequence.  What happens instead is that this output gets repeated *ad infinitum* (or until ctrl-c):

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
etc.
```

What is going on with `cin`?  I know about `getline()`, and could probably solve the problem with it.  But, regardless, I think there is something simple and fundamental that I need to understand about `cin`.  Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


int main(int argc, char **argv) {

   std::vector<int> data;

   int goahead = 1;
   int nextval;

   while (goahead) {

      while (std::cin >> nextval) {
         data.push_back(nextval);
      }

      for (int i=0; i<data.size(); i++) {
         if (i>0) std::cout <<", ";
         std::cout << data[i];
      }
      std::cout << std::endl;

      std::cin >> goahead;
   }

}
```

Comment: `std::cin >> nextval` cannot accept input of *a*. Unless you use `cin.clear()` to remove error flag and then extract the *a* from the stream, you could get an infinite loop of perpetual failed `std::cin >> goahead;` reads with older compilers.

Comment: Why do you need a special character to terminate the input? Can't the user just _terminate the input_? `std::cin` has an implicit unary boolean operator that returns true if the stream is not in an error state. Surely all you need is `while (std::cin) ...` Another way to handle this is with line-based input.

Comment: You keep getting the same data printed out because you do not empty `data`. The easiest way to do this is move the definition of `data` inside the outer while loop so that it is destroyed and recreated on every iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `cin.clear()` and `cin.ignore()` can help:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <limits>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

   std::vector<int> data;

   int goahead = 1;
   int nextval;

   while (goahead) {

      data.clear();
      
      while (std::cin >> nextval) {
         data.push_back(nextval);
      }

      std::cin.clear();
      std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');

      for (int i=0; i<data.size(); i++) {
         if (i>0) std::cout <<", ";
         std::cout << data[i];
      }
      std::cout << std::endl;
      
      std::cin >> goahead;

      std::cin.clear();
      std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');

   }
}
```

Best regards.

Comment: Recommend a tweak: Guard `std::cin >> goahead;`.  `if (!(std::cin >> goahead)) { /*clear and ignore*/ }` If you always `clear`, no harm done, but if you always `ignore` you could discard desired data. And that leads to another point: If the user botches input of `goahead`, you probably want to ask again rather than take whatever value wound up in  `goahead` after the failed read.

Comment: Side note: You should explain what the problem was. It's just a one-liner in this case, but could make all the difference to a future asker with the same question.